# WScript echo is not working in UFT

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, com, hp-uft

I am trying to use WScript in QTP action. But I am getting error as WScript object required.

Example : 
WScript.echo("ICHO") is not working in UFT. 
The same is working if I run using .js or .vbs file.

Answer (score 2):

In vbscript files (or js files) executed under the native windows scripting engine there is an `WScript` object, but this object is not part of the language, it is exposed by the host executable (`cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`) that has instantiated the language engine.

As you are not using any of those hosts, you don't have the `WScript` object available.

Try with

```
Print("ICHO")
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation , I would like to know, is there any possibility to instantiate "cscript.exe" or "wscript.exe" in UFT/QTP ?

Comment: @user2818240, Something like `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cscript.exe myprogram.vbs"` should work, but note that the script will be executed in a separate process